# Force uiviewcontroller to rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I have a UIViewController from which I open MPMoviePlayerViewController, before that the VC isn't allowed to rotate and it doesn't, but the player is allowed. So if I rotate player to landscape and then close it, the VC that isn't suppose to rotate is also in landscape. I have all set to prevent it to rotate, I would just like to know if there is a way, to force VC to check its rotation after I close player.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check the orientation use [UIDevice Orientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/orientation)

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]
```

To change the orientation->

Objective-c:

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Swift:

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just the lines I was looking for, really thank you very much, have spent hours on this, but just couldn't find the lines.

Thanks again